# exam form issues

Tags: php, forms

i am really new on php. I try to make and examination project with php but i have some issues. I have exam form and this form have different type of inputs. For example some questions have combobox, some questions have textarea. I wrote my form code and i wanna learn how can i get all values from the form to the database.

my codes :

```
$question_id = $question_list['question_id'];
$answer_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM answers where question_id = $question_id ORDER BY answer_id ASC");
$total_answers = mysql_num_rows($answer_query);
if ($total_answers > 1)
{
<select name="answers[]" id="answers">                                          <option value="x">please select one</option>
while ($answer_list = mysql_fetch_array($answer_query)) {
<option value="<?PHP echo $answer_list['answer_id']; ?>"><?PHP echo $answer_list_list['answer_value']; ?></option>

else
{
while ($answer_list = mysql_fetch_array($answer_query)) {
<textarea name="answers[]" id="answers" rows="5" cols="100"></textarea>
```

so this is my answer listing part of my exam form. So as you see combobox values getting from database but textarea values will be filled by the users. So how can i get all values (answers from database in combobox (selected value) and textarea values which will be filled by users).

Comment: are you sure that works? you can't start a <textarea> or any tag inside php code, you have to either set it inside a variable or close the `?>` first

Comment: this code has syntax errors. Does it wok at all ?

Comment: you have to use `echo "<textarea name='answers[]'></textarea>"`
You cant directly use html tags inside a `<?php ?>`

Comment: since yo are just now learning code this is a good time for you to forget about mysql, it has been depreciated. look into mysqli or PDO

Comment: idk why ppl downvote his question, he's clearly learning and looking for help, he even posted his code, even if it's wrong.

Comment: this is part of my form. i exactly use php tags in my form. i just wrote the i have different type of inputs. The problem is not php tags as you see. Please read my question before downvote!!!

Answer (score 3):

to get the form values to the database:

The HTML form has to be something like:

```
<form action="insert_into_db.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="answer1" name="answer1"/>
    <textarea id="answer2" name="answer2"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="POST ANSWERS" />
</form>
```

Then in the insert_into_db.php:

```
$answer1=$_POST['answer1'];
$answer2=$_POST['answer2'];
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but how can save these variables to the same column in the table?

Comment: in the same column? you mean in the same field? then you have to insert as many rows as variables, but that would be weird. I guess you really want to insert them in the same ROW, so you just need a `INSERT INTO tablename(fieldname1, fieldname2) VALUES('$answer1', '$answer2')`